# Redirect Subdomains to Subfolders using Htaccess in Hostinger

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdomain

In Hostinger, I have a limit of only 2 free subdomains. So I was looking for an alternative using htaccess. Found and tried almost every related codes on StackOverFlow, but all of them redirect to 404 page. The following is one of my attempt in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

If you observe, I am trying to redirect **http://subdomain.domain.com** to **http://www.domain.com/subdomain/**. I think its mostly my host, which is not allowing me to override their limit of 2 subdomains, but there has to be a way around.

Note:

- I am using CloudFlare for free SSL (Using http only for example in the above code).
- I don't want to change my host, because all my requirements are satisfied except this issue.

Comment: This looks odd to me: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]`. Should it be `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/%1 [L,NC,QSA]` (I removed the `$1`)?

Comment: @TheManiac No luck, still the same :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it should redirect the sub domain to a sub folder:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomain/
RewriteRule (.*) /subdomain/$1
```

I am a little concerned in how it will work with your 2 subdomain limit, below is another alternative for you to try also:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.domain.com/subdomain/?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

EDIT 1:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/.]+)\.domain\.com$ 
RewriteCond %1 !^(www|ftp|mail)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+)$ "http://domain.com/%1" [L,P]
```

EDIT 2:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomain(/|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomain/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Nope, still not working! Though this time, I got 403 error instead.

Comment: Hey @Manikiran, I've added an edit to my answer. Give that a try.

Comment: Thanks you so much for trying it, but still no luck. The helpdesk says they block unregistered subdomains, so only 2 subdomains possible. :)

Comment: No problem mate. Ah that sucks man. Shame there is only a 2 subdomain limit!